# function inside constructor returns undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm struggling to make a code that I found work.

The problem is that the functions defined inside the constructor return `undefined`, so when trying to assign them when events happen, the following error appears:

`Invalid type undefined for OnConnect`

A mininal example is the following (full code at the end of the question)

```
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // this is a function defined inside the constructor
    onConnect = () => {
      // some code
    };

    // but if I try to print it, it returns undefined
    console.log(this.onConnect)
  }
}
```

So the problem is that the definition of this functions is wrong. They use the arrow function and it looks fine to me, so I don't know why it says it's undefined.

Full code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import init from 'react_native_mqtt';
import { AsyncStorage, StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';

init({
  size: 10000,
  storageBackend: AsyncStorage,
  defaultExpires: 1000 * 3600 * 24,
  enableCache: true,
  sync: {},
});

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
});

export default class MqttLog extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    const client = new Paho.MQTT.Client('iot.eclipse.org', 443, 'uname');
    client.onConnectionLost = this.onConnectionLost;
    client.onMessageArrived = this.onMessageArrived;
    client.connect({ onSuccess: this.onConnect, useSSL: true });

    this.state = {
      text: ['...'],
      client,
    };
  }

  pushText = entry => {
    const { text } = this.state;
    this.setState({ text: [...text, entry] });
  };

  onConnect = () => {
    const { client } = this.state;
    client.subscribe('WORLD');
    this.pushText('connected');
  };

  onConnectionLost = responseObject => {
    if (responseObject.errorCode !== 0) {
      this.pushText(`connection lost: ${responseObject.errorMessage}`);
    }
  };

  onMessageArrived = message => {
    this.pushText(`new message: ${message.payloadString}`);
  };

  render() {
    const { text } = this.state;

    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {text.map(entry => <Text>{entry}</Text>)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Your first example differs from the seconds as that in the first, you are creating the `onConnect` function within the constructor itself and in the second, it's in a class level. If you want it to be correct in the first, you'll hgave to create it with `this.onConnect = () => {}`. So this leads me to my question: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Oh, I see, the functions are outside the constructor. I'll fix this. I'm trying to connect to an mqtt server, and get messages so I can update the state.

Comment: It worked. I just missed the alignment so I though the functions were inside the constructor. Now it works, thanks

Comment: Sure thing. I just provided this as an answer as well. Do you want to accept it so people know this is answered?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in the comments:
Your first example differs from the seconds as that in the first, you are creating the onConnect function within the constructor itself and in the second, it's in a class level.

If you want it to be correct in the first, you'll have to create it like this:

```js
export default class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)

    // this is a function defined inside the constructor
    this.onConnect = () => {
      // some code
    };

    // but if I try to print it, it returns undefined
    console.log(this.onConnect)
  }
}
```

The latter code seems correct.